# Function which one must not shadow in Matlab

Tags: matlab, overloading

I am writing some helper functions for unit testing in Matlab. For that I need to overload Matlab functions, built-ins etc. In the documentation is written, that one shall not overload the function `builtin`. I also found out that one must not overload the `lt` operator, since it seems to get called by the UI all the time.

Is there a list of functions which one shall not overload, or do you know of any particular problems from overloading some specific functions?

Further Information:
My use case: I want to do mutation-testing and faul-injection.
in ther words, sometimes the called functions shall return wrong results or throw an error. If I overload the Matlab functions, I do not have to change the source code to do that.

Comment: The general rule is to try to not overload ANY inbuilt, AFAIK. In MATLAB you shadow them, instead of overloading them, i.e. MATLAB will stop knowing about its own functions and only call yours, its not like it will know which one to call in each case (as C++ or other languages do).

Comment: Do you really need to overload standard functions to test your program? Or is that just one approach you came up with?

Comment: @AnderBiguri You are right, i used to wrong terminoloy. I mean shadow. I change the question accordingly.